# Navigate to related list of Account in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, account, related-list

I want to navigate to the related list of accounts with click of the button in LWC.

But when I click on the button I am getting the below error :

> Error in $A.getCallback() [Cannot read property 'errors' of undefined]

```
NavigatetoRelatedlist.js

import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import {NavigationMixin} from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class navigateToRelatedList extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    navigateRelatedListView() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordRelationshipPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Account',
                relationshipApiName: 'Contacts',
                actionName: 'view'
            },
        });
    }
}

NavigatetoRelatedlistHtml

<template>
    <lightning-card title="Navigate to Related List View">
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Related List View"
        onclick={navigateRelatedListView}></lightning-button>

    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Can you help me why i am getting the above error .
Do i need to pass recordID

Comment: The code looks fine to me, it could be another component(aura component)/customization around this object which must be conflicting.Give a try in fresh dev/trial org with same code and check, it should work.

Comment: @ShivankurNaikwade i tried in new dev org but still seeing the same error

Comment: is there more code to this component? Any references to errors within your component in some error handling?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves  yes this is only the code i have checked for error Handling in the [link text]  (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/297165/lwc-navigation-mixin-navigating-successfully-but-throwing-error-first-navigati ) this  post and observed that NavigationMixin's Navigate API does not return a promise.

Comment: @vijayUmmeda, It looks like you have added this button on Home Page and its not having value in 'this.recordId' And so is the reason the error.I was able to reproduce this on home page at my end. If you add the same button on account page, this should work smoothly.

Comment: @ShivankurNaikwade Thanks it's working fine now

Comment: @vijayUmmeda,I am glad that its working for you..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added this button on Home Page and it's not having any value in 'this.recordId' basically, And so is the reason the error.I was able to reproduce this on home page at my end. If you add the same button on account page, this should work smoothly.